# What is wrong this code?

Tags: html

Im an HTML newbie & I can't seem to figure out the problem with the code I've just written. Of course the XXXX's don't count ;-)

I'm certain that the style of this code gets me the result that I want, however the strange thing is thing is that when I run this code on my site or on scratchpad.io (the site that I use to test out code before implementing it)

```
<form action="XXXX" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="FORM_ID" value="XXXX">
<input type="hidden" name="COMPLETE_URL" value=“XXXX”>
.body {
  padding: 20px;
}

* {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 15pt;
      margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
}

.send {
  background: #62b4f5;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 500;
  border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  font-size: 13pt;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0px rgba(173,173,173,0.5);
  margin-left: -6px;
}

.send:hover {
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: 10px 29px;
}

input[type="text"] {
  width: 300px;
  border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0px rgba(173,173,173,0.5);
  outline: none;
}

.suggestion {
  padding: 5px 15px;
}

.suggestion:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}

#autosuggest {
  position: absolute;
  top: 70px;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
  width: 400px;
}
</style>
</form>
```

Comment: There's no opening `<style>` tag.

Comment: What even is the problem? What does it *not* do?

Answer (score 0):

There is no opening tag `<style>` found.